# VPython not responding with Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, vpython

I just installed VPython, but am unable to use it on jupyter notebook. I installed VPython using the instructions on vpython.org. However, when I try to run the following example code (on any kernel):

```
    from visual import *
    sphere()
```

I get the following output:

```
    <visual_common.primitives.sphere at 0x68b3138>
```

and a blank VPython window pops up, with a 'No Responding' on the title bar. This is on windows 8 and python 2.7, and it runs perfectly well on my system otherwise. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the instructions on the first page of vpython.org. You need to import vpython, not visual (visual was the name of the Classic VPython module).